# Python : print a list in a raster view, while preserving the type representation

Tags: python-3.x, list, formatting

How to print a list in a raster view, while preserving the type representation?

For debug purposes, I print the object to verify the data (values) and type (list of tuples) are correct. To simplify reading, I'd like the elements to be neatly arranged in columns.

With

```py
t=[(2, 'Spade'), (2, 'Heart'), (2, 'Diamond'), (2, 'Club'), (3, 'Spade'), (3, 'Heart'), (3, 'Diamond'), (3, 'Club'), (4, 'Spade'), (4, 'Heart'), (4, 'Diamond'), (4, 'Club'), (5, 'Spade'), (5, 'Heart'), (5, 'Diamond'), (5, 'Club'), (6, 'Spade'), (6, 'Heart'), (6, 'Diamond'), (6, 'Club'), (7, 'Spade'), (7, 'Heart'), (7, 'Diamond'), (7, 'Club'), (8, 'Spade'), (8, 'Heart'), (8, 'Diamond'), (8, 'Club'), (9, 'Spade'), (9, 'Heart'), (9, 'Diamond'), (9, 'Club'), (10, 'Spade'), (10, 'Heart'), (10, 'Diamond'), (10, 'Club')]
```

the expected print output would be:

```py
[ (2, 'Spade'),  (2, 'Heart'),  (2, 'Diamond'),  (2, 'Club'), 
  (3, 'Spade'),  (3, 'Heart'),  (3, 'Diamond'),  (3, 'Club'), 
  (4, 'Spade'),  (4, 'Heart'),  (4, 'Diamond'),  (4, 'Club'), 
  (5, 'Spade'),  (5, 'Heart'),  (5, 'Diamond'),  (5, 'Club'), 
  (6, 'Spade'),  (6, 'Heart'),  (6, 'Diamond'),  (6, 'Club'), 
  (7, 'Spade'),  (7, 'Heart'),  (7, 'Diamond'),  (7, 'Club'), 
  (8, 'Spade'),  (8, 'Heart'),  (8, 'Diamond'),  (8, 'Club'), 
  (9, 'Spade'),  (9, 'Heart'),  (9, 'Diamond'),  (9, 'Club'), 
 (10, 'Spade'), (10, 'Heart'), (10, 'Diamond'), (10, 'Club')]
```

My actual code prints the *elements* arranged in columns. I'd like to print the *list* formatted in columns. It's not really important, just for easier debugging.

```py
for i in range(36):
  if i%4 == 0 :
    print(f"\n{str(t[i]):>15s}", end=' ')
  else :
    print(f"{str(t[i]):>15s}", end=' ')
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you're aiming at, but you can create a new class inheriting from `list` with its own `__repr__` method:

```
class raster_list(list):
    def __repr__(self):
        repr_str = "["
        for i in range(len(self)):
            if i%4 == 0 :
                repr_str += f"\n{str(self[i]):>15s}, "
            else :
                repr_str += f"{str(self[i]):>15s}, "
        repr_str += "\n]"
        return repr_str

t=[(2, 'Spade'), (2, 'Heart'), (2, 'Diamond'), (2, 'Club'), (3, 'Spade'), (3, 'Heart'), (3, 'Diamond'), (3, 'Club'), (4, 'Spade'), (4, 'Heart'), (4, 'Diamond'), (4, 'Club'), (5, 'Spade'), (5, 'Heart'), (5, 'Diamond'), (5, 'Club'), (6, 'Spade'), (6, 'Heart'), (6, 'Diamond'), (6, 'Club'), (7, 'Spade'), (7, 'Heart'), (7, 'Diamond'), (7, 'Club'), (8, 'Spade'), (8, 'Heart'), (8, 'Diamond'), (8, 'Club'), (9, 'Spade'), (9, 'Heart'), (9, 'Diamond'), (9, 'Club'), (10, 'Spade'), (10, 'Heart'), (10, 'Diamond'), (10, 'Club')]
t = raster_list(t)
print(t)
```

Output:

```
[ 
   (2, 'Spade'),    (2, 'Heart'),  (2, 'Diamond'),     (2, 'Club'),
   (3, 'Spade'),    (3, 'Heart'),  (3, 'Diamond'),     (3, 'Club'),
   (4, 'Spade'),    (4, 'Heart'),  (4, 'Diamond'),     (4, 'Club'),
   (5, 'Spade'),    (5, 'Heart'),  (5, 'Diamond'),     (5, 'Club'),
   (6, 'Spade'),    (6, 'Heart'),  (6, 'Diamond'),     (6, 'Club'),
   (7, 'Spade'),    (7, 'Heart'),  (7, 'Diamond'),     (7, 'Club'),
   (8, 'Spade'),    (8, 'Heart'),  (8, 'Diamond'),     (8, 'Club'),
   (9, 'Spade'),    (9, 'Heart'),  (9, 'Diamond'),     (9, 'Club'),
  (10, 'Spade'),   (10, 'Heart'), (10, 'Diamond'),    (10, 'Club'),
]
```

Edit: if meddling with classes is too overkill, you can still implement your own `pretty_print` function to get the same output:

```
def pretty_print(l: list):
    repr_str = "["
    for i in range(len(l)):
        if i%4 == 0 :
            repr_str += f"\n{str(l[i]):>15s}, "
        else :
            repr_str += f"{str(l[i]):>15s}, "
    repr_str += "\n]"
    print(repr_str)

pretty_print(t)
```

Comment: This is not what I wanted, sorry if I was not clear. When I print the object `t`, I just want to check the data (values) and type (list of tuples) are correct. For an easier reading, I wanted to present the elements neatly in columns.

Comment: I still don't get what you're after. If you wanna check that all elements are tuples you can use `all(isinstance(x, tuple) for x in t)`. And regarding the arrangement in columns, what's wrong with your code?

Comment: My code prints the _elements_ arranged in columns. I was wondering maybe it's possible to print the _list_ formatted in columns.

Comment: Well how do you think `print` work? it calls `__repr__` for the given list which in turns calls `__repr__` for its elements. So apart from editing `__repr__`, I don't know what you're expecting. I've added the same code as a `pretty_print` function, but like all other methods, it will print the *elements* arranged in the desired way. Another way would be converting your list to another object with the right shape (numpy array, dataframe...) but it's probably even further from what you need.

Comment: OK, thanks. I see your point. I was expecting a list could be printed like a dataframe. But a list is just a sequence of elements, not an array indeed. Thanks anyway for the neat class and function.